# Regular expression to replace a word with another word on the same line unix

Tags: regex, perl, unix, sed, awk

Let A,B,C,D are the words

Input File :

```
..
A/B/C/D 
W/B/C/Z 
L/B/C/O   
..
```

Output file:

```
..
A/B/C/A
W/B/C/W 
L/B/C/L 
..
```

Replace the `word D` with `word A` one the same line, only if  `/B/C/` delimiter present in the line and  like wise  for the other lines

Any `sed/awk/perl` oneliner to accomplish that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed -re 's/^([^/]*)(\/B\/C\/)([^/]*)$/\1\2\1/' file
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file
A/B/C/D
W/B/C/Z
L/B/C/O

$ sed -re 's/^([^/]*)(\/B\/C\/)([^/]*)$/\1\2\1/' file
A/B/C/A
W/B/C/W
L/B/C/L
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! but sorry, my question misguides you! can u please check the question again!!

Comment: @user1228191: I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a `awk` solution:

```
awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '$2=="B" && $3=="C" {$4=$1}1' input.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pearl.306> echo "A/B/C/D"|awk '{split($0,a,"/");print a[1]"/"a[2]"/"a[3]"/"a[1]}'
A/B/C/A
pearl.307>
```

another way is:

```
pearl.309> echo "A/B/C/D" | awk -F"/" '{OFS="/"}{$NF=$1;print}'
A/B/C/A
pearl.310> 

pearl.318> cat file1
A/B/C/D
W/B/C/Z
L/B/C/O
pearl.319> awk -F"/" '{OFS="/"}{$NF=$1;print}' file1
A/B/C/A
W/B/C/W
L/B/C/L
pearl.320>
```

Comment: Can we perform this action onthe total file with a delimiter! can you please check my question again

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's|^\(\(.\)/B/C/\).|\1\2|' file
```

if `A/B/C/D` are real words e.g. `wordA/wordB/wordC/wordD`, then:

```
sed 's/|^\(\([^/]*\)/wordB/wordC/\).*|\1\2|' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. **perl -p -e 's/D/A/g'**

In sed **sed -e 's/D/A/'**

Comment: **perl -p -e 's#^(\w+)(/B/C/)\w+\s*$#\1\2\1#'**

Answer (score 0):

```
 perl -pe 's#(/B/C/)(.*)#$1$`#' file
```

this should work +